# How to make http request to external service in Laravel5?

Tags: api, httprequest, laravel-5

I have an application in Laravel5. What I need is to be able to call an external api and then process the response from the api accordingly.

The response I will get in return is in the form as an xml tag as follows with either `True` or `False`

```
<statusCheck success="true"/>
```

Can someone point me to the right direction that how can I call to external api?

**Note**
Please note that I want to make this request within a `controller` or `model`.

Comment: Take a look at the package [guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GuzzleHttp` to send the HTTP requests.

Download the package through composer:

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "5.0.*@dev"
```

See the documetation on http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: I have now downloaded the package, the question is what is the best way to be able to expose this package in Laravel5. I don't want to use `require` obviously in Laravel5 to have access to library

Comment: Use class reference on the top of your controller class declaration. then create object of Client class. and that's it.

Comment: use GuzzleHttp\Client;

Answer (score 0):

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://foo.com/api/']);
$response = $client->request('GET', 'test');
$response = $client->request('GET', '/root');

return response()->download(public_path($response));
```

we have to user Guzzlehttp client plugin.